# Merge multiple rows with same value into one row in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, merge, dataframe

I have seen that there are similar questions, but the answers did not quite fit my exact needs. I have a dataframe that contains rows with different values. Some of the rows however have exactly the same value.

```
     Column1 Column2 Column3
0       a       x       x
1       a       x       x
2       a       x       x
3       d       y       y
4       d       y       y
```

What I would like to have is:

```
     Column1 Column2 Column3
0       a       x       x
1       d       y       y
```

So basically I want to merge all rows with the same values in all columns into one row. What is the most decent way to do that in python?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates):

```
In [214]:
df.drop_duplicates()

Out[214]:
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       a       x       x
3       d       y       y
```